# Binding text inputs to a directives attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a text input to an attribute within a directive, the reason being I don't want to have to introduce a controller each time I add a new directive of this type. Is this even possible or do you always have to specify a controller when using ng-model. Code example is worth a thousand words so please take a look at http://codepen.io/scottwio/pen/HKqiw . As you type in the input the amount should change.

Comment: Obviously it does. Where's the problem?

Comment: I imagine he wants the animation to replay when the input changes and have it refill the approx amount as entered.  After a quick glace, it looks like it might be a problem with creating an isolate scope using '@' for amount, and a ng model in the template that does not have a dot in it.

Comment: as @Mindstormy suggested as you type in the input the attr.amounts should update so scope.$watch(attrs.amount, function(v){ console.log('changed to '+v);}); fires and logs the new amount. That way I can update the animation whenever the watch is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `scope.$watch(attrs.amount, function (v) {...});` <=>
   `scope.$watch('100', function (v) {...});`
   which is never going to change, so does not do what you want.
2. Since the elements attribute is never going to change, `function draw(aniTime) { var amount = attrs.amount;` is not so usefull.

---

You can fix them like this:

```
scope.$watch('amount', function (v) {...});
```

and

```
function draw(aniTime) {
    var amount = scope.amount;
    ...
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sirJI/)**.

---

<sub>If you want to share the specified amount with the parent scope, then you need to set up a two-way data-binding and specify a property in the parent scope to bind to. E.g.:</sub>

```
// Parent scope
$scope.someAmount = 100;

// In HTML
<custommarc amount="someAmount" ...

// In directive
scope: {
    amount: '='
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @ExpertSystem this fixed. Silly mistake I guess looking at it , now.